# How to resolve a pgAdmin syntax error in my SQL

Tags: pgadmin

I would like to find out which department of the company has the employee earning the lowest salary and once I run this subquery I faced "syntax error"

```
SELECT D.department_name, E.FIRST_NAME
FROM DEPARTMENTS D JOIN EMPLOYEES E
WHERE E.SALARY = (
                  SELECT MIN(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES
                 )
ON D.DEPARTMENT_ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ON` clause needs to be part of the `JOIN`, so it cannot be after the `WHERE` clause.  Try this:

```
SELECT D.department_name, E.FIRST_NAME
FROM DEPARTMENTS D
JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON D.DEPARTMENT_ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE E.SALARY = (
                  SELECT MIN(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

ON clause must come before WHERE, or you can do natural join in the WHERE clause itself:

```
SELECT D.department_name, E.FIRST_NAME
FROM DEPARTMENTS D, EMPLOYEES E
WHERE D.DEPARTMENT_ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID 
AND E.SALARY = (
                  SELECT MIN(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES
               );
```